# When I add more JOINs in a SQL query, it returns a different amount, even though nothing else changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query (in SAP, specifically).

```
SELECT T1.[Name], 
    sum(T0.[U_pptQuota]) AS [Quota] 
FROM OHEM T0 
INNER JOIN OUBR T1 
    ON T0.[branch] = T1.[Code]
```

It returns (correctly) the following info:

```
#   Branches Name           
1   Main    11.40   Y   
2   Mesa    24.70   Y   
3   Phoenix 24.90   Y   
4   Tempe   21.00   Y
```

However, when I add more joins and run this query:

```
SELECT T1.[Name], 
sum(T0.[U_pptQuota]) AS [Quota] 
FROM OHEM T0 
INNER JOIN OUBR T1 
    ON T0.[branch] = T1.[Code] 
INNER JOIN OINV T2 
    ON T0.[empID] = T2.[OwnerCode] 
INNER JOIN INV1 T3 
    ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry] 
GROUP BY T1.[Name]
```

then the returned data suddenly starts returning the following:

```
#   Branches Name   Quota       
1   Main    140.40  Y   
2   Mesa    157.00  Y   
3   Phoenix 20.00   Y   
4   Tempe   265.60  Y
```

Why would adding those selected joins cause the number to change? This doesn't make any sense at all to me.

EDIT: I've updated the query to read as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Name], 
T0.[U_pptQuota] AS [Quota]
FROM OHEM T0 
INNER JOIN OUBR T1 
ON T0.[branch] = T1.[Code]
LEFT JOIN OINV T2 
ON T0.[empID] = T2.[OwnerCode] 
LEFT JOIN INV1 T3 
ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry]
```

This now returns the right amounts in a list

```
#   Branches Name   Quota       
1   Main    0.60    Y   
4   Main    1.80    Y   
6   Main    2.00    Y   
11  Main    3.00    Y   
16  Main    4.00    Y   
2   Mesa    1.20    Y   
7   Mesa    2.00    Y   
12  Mesa    3.00    Y   
15  Mesa    3.50    Y   
20  Mesa    5.00    Y   
23  Mesa    8.00    Y   
3   Phoenix 1.60    Y   
5   Phoenix 1.90    Y   
9   Phoenix 2.10    Y   
14  Phoenix 3.10    Y   
17  Phoenix 4.00    Y   
19  Phoenix 5.00    Y   
22  Phoenix 7.20    Y   
8   Tempe   2.00    Y   
10  Tempe   2.70    Y   
13  Tempe   3.00    Y   
18  Tempe   4.00    Y   
21  Tempe   5.30    Y
```

(When you sum the amounts, they appear to equal the correct amounts)

However, when I add a "SUM" and a "GROUP BY" as in the originals, then it again returns the values that are too high.

EDIT: The way the tables are associated is as follows:

OUBR = the Branch table. Each employee has one branch, and a branch can have more than one employee. PKey = OUBR.Code

OHEM = the Employee table. Each employee has a quota. PKey = OHEM.empID

OINV = the Invoice table. Each invoice has exactly one employee associated with it. An employee will hopefully have more than one invoice. PKey = OINV.DocNum

INV1 = the Invoice sub table (for each different item on the invoice). PKey = INV1.DocEntry

I eventually need to get the following information from a query:

```
BRANCH    QUOTA    TOTAL
```

Where Quota is the sum of all the quotas for each employee in the branch, and TOTAL is the sum of all invoices associated with the employees from each branch.

Comment: Try selecting without a `group by`, I'm fairly sure one of the `joins` produces more rows then you anticipated

Comment: Are EmpId and DocEntry the primary keys of OINV and INV1?  Could you get multiple rows returned from the joins to these tables.  If you remove the sum and just return the results for these two queries, you should soon see the issue.

Comment: you're changing the record set being returned by using those joins.  INNER JOIN means the record must exist in both tables.  Also, if any of those tables have a one to many relationship, you'll get a different number of records returned.  to see, change your select to SELECT * and compare.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, I've updated the question, if  you could take a look again.

Comment: @Paddy, EmpID is not the primary key of OINV. It _is_ the primary key for OHEM.

Comment: In your un-grouped query you select distinct. Obviously there are duplicate records, otherwise you wouldn't have used `distinct`. If you make a subquery using the `distinct` and sum over that in the outer query, the values should be the same again. However, since you do get duplicate rows, you should have a good think whether the join conditions are correct.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, the issue is the way that the tables are associated. I'll add more info to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@phroureo Based on the additional information that you added and the assumptions in my last comment... The query should look something like this:

```
SELECT T1.[Name], 
sum(T0.[U_pptQuota]) AS [Quota],
sum (T4.Total) as Total
FROM OHEM T0 
INNER JOIN OUBR T1 ON T0.[branch] = T1.[Code] 
LEFT JOIN (Select T2.OwnerCode, Sum(T2.PaidSum) AS [Total]
            From OINV T2 
            INNER JOIN INV1 T3  ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry] 
            Group by T2.OwnerCode) T4 ON T0.[empID] = T4.[OwnerCode] 
GROUP BY T1.[Name]
```

Let me know if My assumptions were right.

Comment: For some reason, I don't think that SAP (the program that I'm running these queries from) will allow you to JOIN on a table that you're creating (like you've done with the LEFT JOIN in this case). As I'm sure you can imagine, I'm a little frustrated with this program...

Comment: Just kidding! There was a comma missing that I didn't notice. I believe that it is now correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I can help :-)

Comment: @phroureo BTW, since an employee can have no invoices, I would add isnull() so that your sum doesn't return null... sum (isnull(T4.Total,0)) as Total

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your joins are incorrect.  Not sure what the meaning of the tables are but ON T0.[empID] = T2.[OwnerCode] multiplies entries because you have many T2 records with the same ownerCode and/or ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry] multiplies entries because you have multiple same docEntry values in T3.

Comment: How would I fix it? I'm going to need to use information gathered from the OINV and INV1 tables in the query eventually (OHEM is employee information. OINV and INV1 are related to AR Invoices. Each invoice has an employee assigned to it  by default.)

Comment: @phroureo post the structure of the tables (including Primary Keys) with an explanation of the relations and I will help you solve the issue... Using the distinct as HoneyBadger suggested is dangerous in my opinion since it is hiding the real problem.

Comment: @phroureo Perfect. I just need to understand in your return list I see 4 columns and in your select I see Name and Quota... I suppose the Invoice table contains one record per invoice... "Quota is the sum of all the quotas for each employee" and each employee has 1 quota... "sum of all invoices associated with the employees from each branch" do you have an invoice total in the Invoice Table? or do you need to calculate the invoice totals from the Invoice sub table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix for your problem to get the expected results. But you should still look at the join conditions to see they are really correct.

```
    SELECT     Name
    ,          SUM(Quota) Quota
    FROM       (
                   SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Name], 
                   T0.[U_pptQuota] AS [Quota]
                   FROM OHEM T0 
                   INNER JOIN OUBR T1 
                   ON T0.[branch] = T1.[Code]
                   LEFT JOIN OINV T2 
                   ON T0.[empID] = T2.[OwnerCode] 
                   LEFT JOIN INV1 T3 
                   ON T2.[DocEntry] = T3.[DocEntry] 
               ) DIS
```